# How do nuxt and laravel communicate?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

For a project i want to use nuxt as frontend and laravel serve as an api for the back end. I've cloned a github repo containing a templete including nuxt and laravel. The two are split in two folders, one called front end containing nuxt and one called back end containing laravel.

To be able to use the template in the browser you need to run **php artisan serve** in the back end directory and **npm run dev** in the front end directory.

What i'm curious about is how do these two connect with each other? I can't seem to find where the connection between the front end and back end is made, even tough they don't work without the other.

I know this question might seem a bit weird and/or unclear but if someone could help me that would be great :^)

---

*the github repo: https://github.com/BakayYank/laravel-nuxt-vuetify*

Comment: The documentation says, `cd /frontend` and then `Edit .env and set your api url, default - localhost:8000`. That's your api endpoint for axios XHR requests.

Answer (score 0):

frontend url : `http://localhost:3000`

backend url : `http://localhost:8000/api/`

you can check this file : `frontend/.env`

---

[file link](https://github.com/BakayYank/laravel-nuxt-vuetify/blob/master/frontend/.env)